# Creating 2D coordinates map in Python

Tags: python, iterator, coordinates

I'm not looking for solution, I'm looking for a better solution or just a different way to do this by using some other kind of list comprehension or something else.

I need to generate a list of tuples of 2 integers to get map coordinates like [(1, 1), (1, 2), ..., (x, y)]

So I have the following:

```
width, height = 10, 5
```

**Solution 1**

```
coordinates = [(x, y) for x in xrange(width) for y in xrange(height)]
```

**Solution 2**

```
coordinates = []
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        coordinates.append((x, y))
```

**Solution 3**

```
coordinates = []
x, y = 0, 0
while x < width:
    while y < height:
        coordinates.append((x, y))
        y += 1
    x += 1
```

Are there any other solutions? 
I like the 1st one most.

Comment: I'm fairly sure solution 1 is the best you can come up with.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the list of coordinates?

Comment: At first I'm just writing them to the database to generate a RPG game map for 2D browser game.

Comment: +1 for the first solution by using list comprehension ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
coordinates = list(product(xrange(width), xrange(height)))
```

Comment: `itertools` is a computational saviour.

Comment: +1. I would put it in a function, so that you can just pass in width and height and get the list back.

Comment: Well, I've just done some testing and got the following: creating a generator by list comprehension without [] is the fastest way, but if we are looping through the data afterwards then your method is much faster. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 6):

The first solution is elegant, but you could also use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension:

```
((x, y) for x in range(width) for y in range(height))
```

This might be more efficient, depending on what you're doing with the data, because it generates the values on the fly and doesn't store them anywhere.

This also produces a generator; in either case, you have to use `list` to convert the data to a list.

```
>>> list(itertools.product(range(5), range(5)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), 
 (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 0), 
 (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Note that if you're using Python 2, you should probably use `xrange`, but in Python 3, `range` is fine.

Comment: Using `xrange` in the `itertools.product` class would be more memory efficient, like F.J. did.

Comment: @NiklasR, assuming this is Python 2. If it's Python 3, `xrange` no longer exists. Adding a note though.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED: Added @F.J. answer in the benchmark**

The first implementation is the most pythonic way, and seems to be the fastest, too.
Using `1000` for each, width and height, I register execution-times of

1. `0.35903096199s`
2. `0.461946964264s`
3. `0.625234127045s`

@F.J `0.27s`

So yeah, his answer is the best.

Comment: I assume the *first implementation* is F.J.'s `itertools` solution? And you should provide better descriptions for the numbers.