# python coordinates generator

Tags: python

I need to generate all points coordinates by given dimensions, for example:

```
>>>points(2,2)
>>>[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]
>>>points(1,1,1)
>>>[(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)]
```

I,ve seen [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082829/creating-2d-coordinates-map-in-python) for 2-dimensions, but cant find a way to make method independent of number of dimensions:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(xrange(d) for d in (1,2,3)))
[(xrange(1),), (xrange(2),), (xrange(3),)] #where is my tuples?
```

where (1,2,3) are *args tuple, which can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a * when *calling* the function to use an iterable object as an argument list.
    f(*[1,2,3])
works like
    f(1,2,3).

Knowing this, and using itertools:

```
def points(*args):
  return list(product(*[range(n) for n in args]))
```